# Apple script simulate key events

Tags: applescript, keystroke, keystrokes

I want to know the key codes for all the function keys from F1-F12. From previous search queries I have found keycode 107 to turn brightness down by running this

`echo "tell application \"System Events\"
key code 107
end tell" | osascript`

And I'm guessing that simulates the F1 key but the weird thing is `113` turns the brightness up. I haven't been able to find key codes for any other Fn keys. Any help? Is there a nice table made for this where I can get the keycodes. In the end I want to be able to either directly perform the actions that these keys do or somehow simulate those actions. Anything would be fine.

Comment: You can find the key codes as hexadecimal numbers in this file: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key code 107 is **not** the F1 code; it is a separate code for Brightness control. There is also one for Volume control, but it is broken. The key codes are in semi-random order and can not be predicted. The Function keys are:

F1=122, F2=120, F3=99, F4=118, F5=96, F6=97, F7=98, F8=100, F9=101, F10=109, F11=103, F12=111

[You can find an exhaustive list of Key Codes here](http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html).

Comment: yea I thought so. So how can I simulate these keys and I don't want to simulate F1,F2 and etc... but I want to simulate their actions such as brightness level expose, control center and etc. Using applescript with those keys does not work.

Comment: You can see from the link the codes for brightness up and down. As for all the expose settings, you can invoke with Control+Up arrow and Control+Down Arrow, using the Key codes I shared with you. You can also set more of the functions to Fkeys and then invoke them through those key codes.