# Automator Apple Script for Switching to Next Space

Tags: applescript, spaces, automator

I'm very new to Applescript and I was looking to create an application that automatically switches between the desktops or spaces (as Apple calls them).  Here is the code I have so far:

```
tell application "System Events"
key code 39 using {control down}
end tell
```

If I replace the "key code 39 using {control down}" section with keystroke "n" or any other key letter, it appears to work, but with my current code nothing occurs.  Why would it not be executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code 39 is not the arrow you want for space changes. I found a list of numbers [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236741/using-applescript-to-execute-a-complicated-keystroke) and key code 124 was the equivalent of using the right arrow to switch to the next space in my setup. I plugged that number into your code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 124 using {control down}
end tell
```

And this successfully switched to my next space.

Note that with your code, something did happen when running it inside of Script Editor: an apostrophe was added to the end of the code.

Comment: Funny, it works when I save the script as application but not when executed in Script-Editor.

Comment: Definitely works in Script Editor for me; perhaps its a version issue? I am using OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: My bad, I forgot that I had a little hack running - had to relaunch Script-Editor to reset that and now it works as expected.

Comment: And this answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454072/apple-script-simulate-key-events/27535024#27535024 ) showed a link to an exhaustive list of key codes. On it you can see that key code 39 is the single quote '. (Link is http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html )